# vlc sound menu integration broken 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc, indicator-sound

My sound menu integration of VLC seems to be broken (see screenshot), also the multimedia keys do not work any more. Is there a package I am missing?! The back forward buttons in the sound menu do not work either. I'm running VLC version 2.1.4

- Other players work as expected (such as gnome-mplayer)
- I'm running 14.04, before everything worked fine...

[image]

Edit:Output of `dpkg -l vlc*`

```
ii  vlc            2.1.4-0ubunt amd64        multimedia player and streamer
ii  vlc-data       2.1.4-0ubunt all          Common data for VLC
ii  vlc-nox        2.1.4-0ubunt amd64        multimedia player and streamer (w
ii  vlc-plugin-not 2.1.4-0ubunt amd64        LibNotify plugin for VLC
ii  vlc-plugin-pul 2.1.4-0ubunt amd64        PulseAudio plugin for VLC
```

Edit2:

Since there seems to be no obvious solution to that problem, I submitted a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1331460

Comment: Try logging in with the guest account, and see if it works there. If it does, then something is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

- Reinstall VLC:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc vlc-data vlc-nox
  sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-data vlc-nox
  ```
- Verify DBus plugin for VLC:

  ```
  $ ls -l /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libdbus_plugin.so
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72760 May 17 15:56 /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/libdbus_plugin.so
  ```

  VLC → Tools → Plugins & Extensions → Plugins tab → Is there *D-Bus control interface*?
- Run VLC and check if it creates an MPRIS DBus service, example:

  ```
  $ gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.DBus \
  --object-path / --method org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames | \
  awk 'BEGIN { RS=","; } /org.mpris.MediaPlayer2./ { gsub(/[\[\]()\x27]/, ""); print $1; }'

  org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
  org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance18027
  ```

  (Try also with other working player, to confirm that you run the command correctly)

  Other way, you may use `qdbusviewer` → session bus tab → search for `vlc`
- If DBus interface listed, check if VLC respond correctly:

  ```
  gdbus call --session \
      --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
      --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
      --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
      "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player" \
      "PlaybackStatus"
  ```

  Output may be: `(<'Playing'>,)`, `(<'Paused'>,)` or `(<'Stopped'>,)`

  or using `qdbus`

  ```
  qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc \
      /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
      org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
      org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player PlaybackStatus
  ```

  It should output: `Playing` , `Paused` or `Stopped`

**At this point, VLC player works as it should. So it is out of circle.**

- Reinstall indicator-sound and reset its config:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-sound
  sudo apt-get install indicator-sound unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-webaccounts

  dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/sound/
  rm -rf ~/.cache/indicators/sound
  ```

  `pkill -f indicator-sound-service` or Logout/login
- No success, run it in terminal & watch for errors

  Locate its executable:

  ```
  $ sudo updatedb
  $ locate -br indicator-sound-service$
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
  ```

  Rename it, to stop respawn, then kill its running process:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service0
  pkill -f indicator-sound-service
  ```

  Run it again:

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service0
  ```

  Run VLC, try use its control on sound menu, any error messages?
- Try build new indicator-sound from source:

  ```
  sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound
  apt-get source indicator-sound
  cd indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140313/
  mkdir build
  cd build/
  cmake ..
  make
  ```

  Stop running one as previous step, then run without installing it:

  ```
  ./src/indicator-sound-service
  ```

Comment: The weirdest thing is, that all the other players work as expected... If I want to file a bug report, for which package should i file it? What do you suggest? Thanks for the help, if there's no better answer coming I'm going to accept yours...

Comment: @wa4557, `indicator-sound` as VLC is stand alone foreign app, and the bug effects appear on sound menu. I suggest leaving it open (unaccepted). no other idea

Comment: @wa4557, I saw the bug report be orphan (both packages set a invalid :/) . What's output of `gdbus call --session --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' 'CanControl'`

Answer (score 0):

Inside VLC go to :

Tools > Preferences, select "All" under "Show settings" (bottom left), then navigate to Interface > Control Interface and check the box next to "D-Bus control interface"

Comment: there is no such setting for vlc 2.1.