# Ubuntu 14.04 - Top right sound screen icon, greyed and not working

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

I can hear rythmbox songs and Internet videos perfectly, but my screen sound icon is always greyed and muted, and I cannot use it for turn up and down sound volume...

Any advice would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try steps related to indicator-sound here https://askubuntu.com/questions/481713/vlc-sound-menu-integration-broken-14-04/483692#483692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I solved the question using the first answer for that question > 
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/33089/what-user-settings-control-audio-access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33089/what-user-settings-control-audio-access%20askubuntu%20What%20user%20settings%20control%20audio%20access?)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem on Ubuntu 16.04.
I used this to fix the problem:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse
```